# ts-node-dev no hace live reload en linux

Tags: nodejs, linux, typescript

Buenas tengo una API en TypeScript la cual para el entorno de desarrollo uso "ts-node-dev" el problema esta en que en mi entorno linux no esta funcionando el reload al hacer un cambio en los archivos.

Este es el script de arranque en el package.json

```
    "dev:backend": "export NODE_ENV=dev && ts-node-dev --unhandled-rejections=strict --ignore-watch node_modules --inspect=0.0.0.0:9267 src/apps/Backend/server.ts",
```

Lo extraño es que si cambio el EXPORT por SET para que funcione en WINDOWS. En este si funciona, si hace el live reload.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede, es que `export` no es un comando displonible en Windows tal como lo es en GNU/Linux.

Hay unas cuantas formas de solucionarlo, Una de ellas es usar un script de NodeJS que verifique en sistema operativo se está ejecutando. Para ello, puedes implementar la propiedad integrada `process.platform`:

```javascript
const child_process = require('child_process') // Esta dependencia global viene incluida en la instalación de NodeJS

let customCommand = 'echo "Comando no definido"'

switch (process.platform) {
  case 'win32': // para Windows
    customCommand = 'set NODE_ENV=dev'
    break
  default: // Asumimos que por defecto se ejecutará en un sistema POSIX
    customCommand = 'export NODE_ENV=dev'
    break
}

child_process.exec(
  customCommand + '&& ts-node-dev --unhandled-rejections=strict --ignore-watch node_modules --inspect=0.0.0.0:9267 src/apps/Backend/server.ts', // Executamos el comando
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`)
      return
    }
    if (stdout) {
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
    }
    if (stderr) {
      console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    }
  }
)
```

---

Referencias:

1. [process.platform (respuesta en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684009/7737346)
2. [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)
3. [Comando `set` (en inglés)](https://superuser.com/questions/1500272/equivalent-of-export-command-in-windows)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información. Creo que no me he explicado suficientemente bien, pero mi problema no es con el comando EXPORT - SET  (linux -windows). Si no con el script para correr el ts-node-dev en (linux con el export) no me funciona el live reload. Hago cambios en los archivos, pero no hace live reload. En cambio si modifico el script por el SET y lo corro en windows si me hace el live-reload. Disculpa si no me supe explicar y muchas gracias por tu disposición en contestar.